# Warning for 'pattern' attribute in razor view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html, razor

I have an input in razor view:

```
<input id="age" title="test" type="number" name="test" pattern="" value="15" />
```

In Visual Studio I get a warning:

> Validation (HTML5): Attribute 'pattern' is not a valid attribute of
>   element 'input'

This attribute is available via intellisense. Why this warning?

Comment: its depend on version !! which version of visual studio?

Comment: @vishalshama VS 12 Pro

Comment: see my answer , open dropdown and select HTML5 FROM Target Schema For Validation

Comment: ADD TITLE TO THAT AS PATTERN REQUIRED TITLE ATTRIBUTE TOO..Attribute is only allowed when title is present

Comment: @vishalsharma Thanks for answer. But the problem was in <type> attribute. (It wasn't needed to uppercased your answer :)

Comment: accept answer or add your's one if you found solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works without 'type' attribute:

```
<input id="age" title="test" name="test" pattern="" value="15" />
```

..And warning is gone.

Answer (score 0):

Html5 Support has been there for visual studio 
i haven't find any link about in which version it is added

but how to do that? is by selecting html5 in Target Schema For Validation

[image: visual studio mark up selection]

also Title property is required when you want to use pattern attribute

Comment: I have this option in view selected by default.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure your page Doctype is not like this.

`<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org /TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">`

use the noraml html5 doctype as

`<!Doctype html>`

Comment: Where should I put this?

Comment: Try to put in your masterpage.

Comment: I have it in my layout page and I use this layout in all pages.

Comment: Did you try by giving value to the pattern attribute?

Comment: Yes, I gave it a value, launched application but validation is not working.